# Unable to scrape data from a website

Tags: python, angularjs, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get the price of a item from this website :https://paytm.com/shop/p/demonio-SUNDEMONIOS-R-193973BC69538C?tracker=%7C%7C%7C%7C%2Fh%2Fbrand-store%2Ffashion-sale-Best-Selling%20Products%7C1

The price is located in the following tag:

```
<span ng-if="!product.product.isOnlyCarCategory">Buy for Rs 79</span>
```

I use the following code , but it returns an empty list.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s=str(raw_input())
r=requests.get(s)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
item_name=soup.find_all("span",{"ng-if":"!product.product.isOnlyCarCategory"})
print item_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the json that contains the product data, by appending `&callback=angular.callbacks._0&channel=web&version=2` to the URL.

`https://catalog.paytm.com/v1/p/demonio-SUNDEMONIOS-R-193973BC69538C?tracker=%7C%7C%7C%7C%2Fh%2Fbrand-store%2Ffashion-sale-Best-Selling%20Products%7C1&callback=angular.callbacks._0&channel=web&version=2`

You can then parse the result like this (I assume you are interested in the price):

```
import json
import requests

r = requests.get(url)
d = json.loads(r.text.split('\n')[1][:-2])
print(d['offer_price'])
```

The above will give you `79`.